# How to run java jar file on LAN

Tags: java

We created a desktop Application on java using swingx. we want to run the jar file generated on multiple system having centralized db. i have run separate jar on each system using the same db setting but data are not saving properly.

Answer (score 1):

In the fewest cases it is recommended to have several clients to access the db directly. Rather the db should be accessed via a server component such as a Java EE application using EJBs.

A Java EE application can provide Swing clients e.g. using Java WebStart. The Swing clients can access the server logic with e.g. remote EJBs (in a LAN) or using WebServices.

Answer (score 0):

set ip address instead of localhost in the code where database path is set 
&better to be use a 4th type of jdbc driver